# Starting on Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I was following a tutorial on medium 
[Tutorial Link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-blockchain-network-using-hyperledger-fabric-and-composer-e06644ff801d?_branch_match_id=582194111361612536)
and his transaction structure and mine were different, his was:
[image: Submit Transaction]
and mine was:
[image: my trasaction]

Answer (score 1):

you can try to have a look at this file **tradenotif-tradecard.cto**
at the transaction **TradeCard**

it should looks like this

```
transaction TradeCard {
--> TradingCard card
--> Trader newOwner
}
```

looks like you are missing the field newOwner.